# call function x number of times and execute it from another script

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, execute

I am running 2 python scripts, say `main.py` and `test.py`
In main.py i am executing `get_details` function "x" number of times every 30 seconds.

NOTE: I want to execute funA,funcB funC in sequence. The issue i am facing here is - when i run test.py, it first runs funcC(), even though i am calling funcA() first.

test.py

```
def funcA():
    #do something
    funcB()

def funcB():
    #do something
    funcC()

def funcC():
    #here i want to execute script main.py
    #My attempt 1 :  
    import subprocess
    import sys
    theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "main.py"])
    theproc.communicate() 

    #------OR-----------

    #My attempt 2: 
    execfile("main.py")
```

main.py

```
import threading
def get_details(a,b,c):
    #do something ...        


class RepeatEvery(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, func, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval  # seconds between calls
        self.func = func          # function to call
        self.args = args          # optional positional argument(s) for call
        self.kwargs = kwargs      # optional keyword argument(s) for call
        self.runable = True
    def run(self):
        while self.runable:
            self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            time.sleep(self.interval)
    def stop(self):
        self.runable = False

thread = RepeatEvery(30, get_details,"arg1","arg2","arg3")
print "starting"
thread.start()
thread.join(21)  # allow thread to execute a while...
```

I want to execute script main.py only after all functions (funcA,funcB) executed properly. But in my case, main.py executed first and then control goes back to test.py and it executes funcA() and funcB().

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I rewrote your code so it would work as you said it should.

main.py...

```
#Good design for small classes: keep global functions separate for people who want
#to explore the type, but not everything that comes along with it.
#I moved the the global functions and code execution from top and bottom to test.py

import threading
import time #You forgot to import time.

class RepeatEvery(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, func, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval  # seconds between calls
        self.func = func          # function to call
        self.args = args          # optional positional argument(s) for call
        self.kwargs = kwargs      # optional keyword argument(s) for call
        self.runable = True
    def run(self):
        while self.runable:
            self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            time.sleep(self.interval)
    def stop(self):
        self.runable = False

    """ We couuuld have done this, but why bother? It is hard to work with.
    def get_details(self,a,b,c):
    #do something else as a function of the class...
    """
```

test.py...

```
import main #File where class lives.

def funcA():
    #do something
    print ("In A...") #Helps us observe scope.
    funcB()

def funcB():
    #do something
    print("In B...") #scope
    funcC()

def funcC():
    #here i want to execute script main.py
    #My attempt 1 :
    print("In C...") #scope
    main() #Reached C, lets run main now...

    #This is one way to do allow a function to be accessible to your class.
def get_details(a,b,c): 
    #do something else as a function of ¬[class] test.py operating on 
    #a RepeatEvery object...
    pass

def main(): #Function main is separate from class main. It houses our opening code.
    thread = main.RepeatEvery(30, get_details,"arg1","arg2","arg3")
    print ("starting")
    thread.start()
    thread.join(21)  # allow thread to execute a while...

funcA()
```